# what does a developer need to do to adapt to cloud environment

Tags: cloud

is it as simple as using a cloud server? or do i need to change my code ? i do nothing ? if yes ; what steps do i take to make my code cloud friendly ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cloud is just a buzzword that came about to describe the trend that more and more software is available as a service running 'up there'.  Its tied to the term Software as a Service.  There is no such thing as a 'cloud server'. There are just servers running services.  Those services might be WebServices, RESTful web services, or specific programs.  For example, Google Docs is a cloud service -- your data is stored on their servers, or 'in the cloud'.  You don't need to do anything to maintain/setup the service, it is just available.

For developers, everything stays the same.  You really just use the APIs (SOAP WS, REST WS, jsonp,  etc) that you need for the services you are accessing.